# Confusion about using U and UL after constants to have correct calculations

Tags: c, embedded

I am using this mapping function to map values from 0-1023 to 0-255

function `mapping_function` takes 16-bit unsigned integer value as input to be mapped to 0-255

function is declared as following

```
uint16_t mapping_function(uint16_t x)
{
    return (x*255)/1023;
}
```

Problem is, it is not working like this. value mapped is incorrect and result in unexpected values for result (function return)

it works only if I declared it like following:

```
uint16_t mapping_function(uint16_t x)
{
        return (x*255UL)/1023;
}
```

using UL "unsigned long" literal after the first constant.

OR

defined x variable as float like following :

```
uint16_t mapping_function(float x)
{
        return (x*255)/1023;
}
```

I doubt that this occurs due to overflow issue, but i cannot understand why ?
I appreciate any help.. thanks :D

Comment: `I doubt that this occurs due to overflow issue` it is, 16bit int has max value 65535, so 1000*255 (any value above 256 actually) - overflows

Comment: Just to add what @IłyaBursov said the type of (x*255) is uin16.  In your working examples the type of that expression is unsigned long and float respectively.  So in your working examples the calculation is done with higher precision then the result is cast to your return type.  If you want to look at the standard the concept is rank used for type promotion (6.3.1).

Comment: What size is `int` on that platform? (Default promotions). If 32 bits, the intermediate calculation should not overflow. If 16 bits, it can.

Comment: Aside: shouldn't the calculation be `x * 256 / 1024`? And then, you can do it with `x >> 2` without overflow.

Comment: @Msamy, "value mapped is incorrect "  --> Reduce the mystery.  What value did you get?

Comment: @IłyaBursov, yes I got it, you are right , thanks :D, actually calculation are going will when x is <=256. >>257*255=65535, and this is the point at which overflow occurs. Knowing that x ranges from 0 to 1023, then overflow must occur above 256.
 for example when x = 266 the function returns 2, and when it is 481, function returns 55... etc

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica
Sorry for not being clear, here is example of WRONG results 
for example when x = 266 the function returns 2, and when it is 481, function returns 55... etc

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, Neat implementation. I never thought about this conversion to be like this because I am using more general equation to map between any values in case the minimum is not equal 0
`((((x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min)) / (in_max - in_min)) + out_min)`
However, thanks for your note :D
and size of int is 32 Bits in my platform

Comment: If your `int` is 32 bits then I don't understand why you are getting an overflow with those values. The values are promoted to `int` during the calculation, for precisely the reason that the intermediate value does *not* overflow.

Comment: @Msamy With 32-bit `int`, please post a [mcve] to help us all find what is going wrong.

Comment: I truly don'tt understand why you are dividing by 1023, as two byte integer has 65536 values, which is 64 full ranges of 1023 values plus an extra 64 values that are mapped differently.  Why don't you divide by `1024` in which case you will have exactly 64 ranges of 1024 values?  from 0 to 1023 is exactly 1024 values, but you divide by 1023, leaving 64 values of the range outside.  Why?

Answer (score 2):

With 16-bit `int/unsigned`: overflow.

---

`x*255` is a `uint16_t` * `int`.

16-bit `int/unsigned`: the math product is an `unsigned` and with large enough `x`, truncated due to **overflow**.

32-bit `int/unsigned`: the product in an `int` and as expected for all `x`.

---

`x*255UL` is a `uint16_t` * `unsigned long`.

32-bit `long/unsigned long`: the product in an `unsigned long` and as expected for all `x`.

64-bit `long/unsigned long`: the product in an `unsigned long` and as expected for all `x`.

---

Rather than use `L`, which may be excessively wide or no `L` and the constant too narrow, and since the product may be wider than 16-bits, for portable code to all systems where `int/unsigned` may be 16,32, ..., use `UINTN_C(value)`.

It forms a minimum width constant and performs the multiplication with at least 32-bit unsigned math.

```
#include <stdint.h>
...
  return (x*UINT32_C(255))/1023;
```

---

I also doubt OP's mapping is best. [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74970933/confusion-about-using-u-and-ul-after-constants-to-have-correct-calculations/74971461#comment132300819_74970933)

Consider:

```
return (x*256UL)/1024;
// or 
return x>>2;
```

Comment: The OP's mapping is not good. I doubt the OP actually confirmed that each of the 1024 10 bit values was properly mapped into 8 bits. Using the OP conversion, 0x3FF is the only value that maps down to 0xFF, while interspersed are a few ranges at which 5 values map to a single 8 bit value...